# C# Code Not Executing

Tags: c#, wpf

I have a C#/WPF application with a tabbed interface that has been behaving strangely. After thinking originally my problems were related to the TabControl, I now believe that it's something different and I'm completely stuck. The following method is just supposed to pull some data out of the database and load a couple of WPF ComboBoxes. The strange thing is that the code reaches a certain point, specifically the end of the loop that loads cboState's Item collection, and then continues on. No code placed below that loop executes, no errors are thrown than I can find or see, and no breakpoints placed below that loop ever get reached. I'm completely perplexed.

```
private void loadNewProjectTab() {
    dpDate.SelectedDate = DateTime.Now;

    cboProjectType.Items.Add("Proposal");
    cboProjectType.Items.Add("Pilot");
    cboProjectType.SelectedIndex = -1;

    string sql = "SELECT State FROM States ORDER BY ID";
    OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand(sql, connection);
    if(connection.State == ConnectionState.Closed) {
        connection.Open();
    }

    OleDbDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
    while(reader.HasRows) {
        reader.Read();
        cboState.Items.Add(reader["State"].ToString().Trim());
    } // <-- Nothing below here executes.

    connection.Close();
}
```

Comment: I believe this is because exception has been thrown, enable exceptions in `Visual Studio menu -> Debug -> Exceptions -> CLR exceptions`

Comment: is `loadNewProject` calling any try/catch statements?

Comment: Inability to hit breakpoints on certain lines that you think should get hit often means that your code base is out of sync with what gets executed (i.e. the exe is stale because of build errors).

Comment: is `Items` a custom collection that has `goto`s in it's `Add` method?

Comment: Try while(reader.Read() and get rid of it inside your loop. What does debugging the program says about the data in your reader-object?

Comment: sll: You are completely correct. Thank you thank you. I've been scratching my head about that all day today. An exception was being thrown because I was reading past the end of that data. Why in the Heck did VS2010 require something to be turned ON before I was able to see this error? Ridiculous.

Comment: Is the column "State" null in one or more rows?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
while(reader.HasRows) { 
    reader.Read(); 
    cboState.Items.Add(reader["State"].ToString().Trim()); 
}
```

`reader.HasRows` will return true even after you've read all the rows and moved past the last one with `reader.Read()`; at that point, you'll get an exception on `reader["State"]`.

Since `reader.Read()` returns a boolean to indicate whether there's a current row, you should skip calling `reader.HasRows` entirely:

```
while(reader.Read()) { 
    cboState.Items.Add(reader["State"].ToString().Trim()); 
}
```

Comment: This is exactly what was happening and exactly how I fixed it. The original error (code not executing, didn't know why) was caused by the exception being thrown but VS2010 not notifying me without changing a setting.

Answer (score 2):

Um I think is wrong your loop it should be.

```
if (reader.HasRows)
{
    while(reader.Read()) 
    {         
        cboState.Items.Add(reader["State"].ToString().Trim());
    } 
}
```

Note that the bucle is with  `while(reader.Read())`

Comment: The HasRows is not necessary.

Comment: I agree. I just let it for avoiding confuse to the OP

Answer (score 2):

This is your problem:

```
while(reader.HasRows) {
    reader.Read();
    cboState.Items.Add(reader["State"].ToString().Trim());
}
```

`HasRows` indicates whether or not the reader retrieved anything; it doesn't change as you read through it (in other words, it's not analogous to an end-of-file indicator like you're using it). Instead, you should do this:

```
while(reader.Read()) {
    cboState.Items.Add(reader["State"].ToString().Trim());
}
```

Answer (score 2):

`Reader` should be closed.

```
using(var reader = cmd.ExecuteReader())
{
    if(reader.HasRows)
    {
        while(reader.Read()) 
        {
            cboState.Items.Add(reader["State"].ToString().Trim());
        } 
    }
}
```